# What start up scripts are executed when a terminal(shell) is opened in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, terminal

When I open a terminal, it says cannot execute the binary file and the output is something like this:

```
bash: /home/sandeep/bin/uname: cannot execute binary file

bash: [: =: unary operator expected

bash: /home/sandeep/bin/sed: cannot execute binary file

bash: /home/sandeep/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

This is followed by normal prompt where everything is fine. But as a programmer it is annoying to see those many errors every time you open a terminal.

The Reason i found out is that when i installed a armeabi tool chain it created a folder called bin in the home directory and all the executables inside this directory are for arm processor. But my terminal when it is being opened it is trying to execute these arm binaries and hence it shows an error that these binaries cannot be executed(since my proc is not arm)

To solve this i can remove this folder(i tried it and it worked) but thats not the optimal solution. i want to know the script that is getting executed when i open a terminal where it is trying to execute wrong binaries at the launch.

I had a look at .bashrc but there is nothing relevant to my problem in that.

Comment: I suppose it belongs to http://askubuntu.com/ (I don't see this option in my "flag as offtopic" list of suggested places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd debug it with strace

```
strace -e trace=open,read bash > output.txt
```

then you can check what files are getting opened when calling bash

Comment: +1 to the solution.Hi Chris, Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain the instruction. It would be really helpful..

Comment: Hi. The strace command tracks systemcalls of any specific command. With open,read it basically shows what files are opened or read when running the command "bash" (you could use any other command instead of bash). This way you can debug what files are called when opening a new session. You should see some bashrc that is being read and also the scripts that you call in those files. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove /home/sandeep/bin from $PATH environment variable.

Comment: Or move it to the last thing. Whenever I am setting `PATH` I always do `export PATH=$PATH:/new/dir/bin`.